# Issue with Rendering Table of Contents using Sphinx in Flask API Template

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, tableofcontents, autodoc

I have managed to successfully render the body of my package and its modules using Sphinx. However, I'm encountering an issue with the readability of the table of contents.

The current output of the table of contents looks as follows:

```
MyPackage
    MyModule
        MyClassXXXXXXXX
            MyClassXXXXXXXX...
            MyClassXXXXXXXX...
            MyClassXXXXXXXX...
            MyClassXXXXXXXX...
            MyClassXXXXXXXX...
```

In other words, the table of contents with this structure does not render correctly.

```
MyPackage
    MyModule
        MyClass1
            MyClass1.attr1
            MyClass1.attr2()
        MyClass2
            MyClass2.attr1
            MyClass2.attr2()
```

How can I prevent the redundant repetition of the class name in the structure? For example, I would prefer the format to appear as such:

```
MyPackage
    MyModule
        MyClass1
            attr1
            attr2()
        MyClass2
            attr1
            attr2()
```

This is my first time using sphinx, so please let me know if any additional context is needed improve the clarity of my question.

Any guidance on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.